# How to check if Meteor's users account is empty?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to create a default user when my Meteor application starts, so I check if there is any user in the users collection, but it doesn't work.

I try this:

```
if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
  seedUserId = Accounts.createUser({
    email: 'f@oo.com',
    password: '123456'
  });
}
```

This count() return 0, but in Mongo I have users:
`meteor:PRIMARY> db.users.find().count()`
`>>              2`

I try this too:
`Meteor.users.findOne()`
but returns undefined...

What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Are you doing this on server or client side?

Comment: server side @Soren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be seeing a race condition where the server is not fully loaded when your code is executing -- try to wrap your code in `Meteor.startup` like;

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
       seedUserId = Accounts.createUser({
          email: 'f@oo.com',
          password: '123456'
       });
    }
  });
}
```